# How can i get the equal or nearest values of a row in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find rows with column values are equal to eachother. Or maybe little different then other (1, 0.5 and etc.) or even at least 2 columns are equal.

```
df.head(10)

         a        b        c        d
0  1128.70  1137.00  1121.30  1132.05
1  1130.20  1142.30  1109.10  1114.90
2  1113.40  1127.90  1109.85  1124.55
3  1126.25  1129.30  1111.20  1124.50
4  1124.45  1141.10  1121.00  1137.95
5  1137.90  1141.90  1094.50  1098.25
6  1097.60  1117.00  1095.65  1112.50
7  1111.05  1119.10  1089.85  1092.10
8  1092.75  1097.60  1074.10  1083.75
9  1083.60  1096.05  1079.10  1087.20
```

in the table above, i am trying to find rows with values equal to eachother (or close to eachother). Let's say:

```
125  1020.50  1020.50  1020.50  1020.50
452  1047.88  1047.88  1046.95  1048.01
```

Comment: Can you define what the tolerance of similar numbers is? A difference of 1, 10, etc?

Comment: actually "n" is the tolerance. So it can be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just look at the standard deviation?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 1128.7, 1: 1130.2, 2: 1113.4, 3: 1126.25, 4: 1124.45, 5: 1137.9, 6: 1097.6, 7: 1111.05, 8: 1092.75, 9: 1083.6, 125: 1020.5, 452: 1047.88}, 'b': {0: 1137.0, 1: 1142.3, 2: 1127.9, 3: 1129.3, 4: 1141.1, 5: 1141.9, 6: 1117.0, 7: 1119.1, 8: 1097.6, 9: 1096.05, 125: 1020.5, 452: 1047.88}, 'c': {0: 1121.3, 1: 1109.1, 2: 1109.85, 3: 1111.2, 4: 1121.0, 5: 1094.5, 6: 1095.65, 7: 1089.85, 8: 1074.1, 9: 1079.1, 125: 1020.5, 452: 1046.95}, 'd': {0: 1132.05, 1: 1114.9, 2: 1124.55, 3: 1124.5, 4: 1137.95, 5: 1098.25, 6: 1112.5, 7: 1092.1, 8: 1083.75, 9: 1087.2, 125: 1020.5, 452: 1048.01}})

           a        b        c        d
0    1128.70  1137.00  1121.30  1132.05
1    1130.20  1142.30  1109.10  1114.90
2    1113.40  1127.90  1109.85  1124.55
3    1126.25  1129.30  1111.20  1124.50
4    1124.45  1141.10  1121.00  1137.95
5    1137.90  1141.90  1094.50  1098.25
6    1097.60  1117.00  1095.65  1112.50
7    1111.05  1119.10  1089.85  1092.10
8    1092.75  1097.60  1074.10  1083.75
9    1083.60  1096.05  1079.10  1087.20
125  1020.50  1020.50  1020.50  1020.50
452  1047.88  1047.88  1046.95  1048.01

>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.std(df.values, axis=1)

array([  5.70869676,  13.02005664,   7.50120824,   6.92101645,
         8.56084838,  21.84866629,   9.22688836,  12.40707963,
         8.97754142,   6.22217556,   0.        ,   0.42479407])
```

You can see that your last two example rows have much lower standard deviations, `0` if all the values are equal. Now you can just compare against a threshold:

```
>>> n = 1
>>> np.std(df.values, axis=1) < n

array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Sorry i was away for a while. But how can i get these values from DataFrame? I mean let's say i have assigned return array to "arr". How can i get rows equals to this array from DataFrame?

Comment: I have got the idea. That's a perfect solution for me. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

you could convert your data in numpy array. npData

then 
`rowIndex = [iter for iter in range(npData.shape[0]) if np.std(npData[iter,1:]) <= threshold]`

something like that ?
you may need a "normalization" of your data for the thresholding based on std.

or use the zscore from scipy on the npData array along the good axis https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html, and then use this zscored array to find rows where the sum of each absolute value of the colomn is <= threshold

best solution I found for the at least 2 columns equal:

```
`from itertools import combinations
 n=2
 test=[]
 for (x1,x2) in combinations(df.values.T,2):
    diff = numpy.where(abs(x1-x2)<n)
    test = numpy.union1d(test,diff[0])`
```

or just append test and then do a numpy.histogram to find when at least three or more columns are equal